# MNIST Tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I am struggling  with this command
`from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data`

I am using Anaconda , and tried really a lot of possibilities , python version 3.5.4 3.6 3.8 ...
tensorflow 2 tensorflow  1.14 1.8 ...
still ***not*** **successful** :|
so i tried to do that manually , i mean copying pasting files inside tensorflow directory i.e. [C:\Users\USERI\anaconda3\envs\MYtf0\Lib]

still ***not*** **successful** :|

i know there is another way using keras , it works fine with keras
`(X_train, y_train) , (X_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()`

but i will lose all the methods coming with [input_data] from [tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist] .. such as = [mnist.train.next_batch]

Any help , please :/
and Thank you in advance.

Comment: What error are you getting exactly ?

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.examples'